# How to persist entity with collection inside by using Hibernate?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, orm

I'm trying to persist an entity in my DB using *Hibernate ORM*. My `entity class`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Collection<Employee> employees;
```

Repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class HibernateCompanyRepository implements CompanyRepository {

    @Autowired
    HibernateTemplate template;

    @Override
    public Company getCompany(int id) {
        return template.get(Company.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Company> getCompanies() {
        return template.loadAll(Company.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCompany(Company employee) {
        template.save(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCompany(int id) {
        template.delete(template.get(Company.class, id));
    }

    @Override
    public void updateCompany(Company company) {
        template.update(company);
    }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/company")
public class CompanyController {

    @Autowired
    CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}",
                    method = RequestMethod.GET,
                    produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody public Company getCompany(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        return companyRepository.getCompany(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT,
                    consumes = "application/json",
                    headers = "content-type=application/json")
    public String updateCompany(@RequestBody Company company) {
        companyRepository.updateCompany(company);
        return "redirect:/company/" + company.getId();
    }

    // another methods ommited    
}
```

Old JSON

```
{
  "name" : "IBM",
  "employees" : [
    {
      "name" : "John",
      "id" : 2
    },
    {
      "name" : "Bill",
      "id" : 4
    }
  ],
  "id" : 2
}
```

Updated JSON (Bill was deleted)

```
{
  "name" : "IBM",
  "employees" : [
    {
      "name" : "John",
      "id" : 2
    }
  ],
  "id" : 2
}
```

I receive an Employee entity in my `updateCompany()` method. `Entity` has been succesfully updated. It has changed collection of Employee (for example I removed one employee). But Hibernate can't persist this updated entity. When I'm trying to retrieve it I see no changes happend. Any suggestions how to fix it?

UPD:

I'm trying to update my deleted employees first

```
@Override
public void updateCompany(Company company) {
    Company oldCompany = getCompany(company.getId());
    for (Employee employee : oldCompany.getEmployees()) {
        if (!company.getEmployees().contains(employee)) {
            employee.setCompany(null);
            template.update(employee);
        }
    }
    template.update(company);
}
```

And get exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [eu.flavio.restful.entity.Company#2]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [eu.flavio..restful.entity.Company#2]
```

Answer (score 0):

What matters to Hibernate is the owner side of the bidirectional association. The owner side is the side which does NOT have the `mappedBy` attribute. That's where it looks to find if an association netween entities exist of not.

The owner side here is thus `Employee.company`. `Company.employees` is the inverse side. You must make sure that Bill's company is set to null if you want Bill not to be part of IBM anymore.